# how to deal with $_POST for a variable which is set as name of a input in a form - PHP

Tags: php, post

this is where I used `$fieldName` & `$fieldValue` in name and value input. these input types are in thousands.I have to store their info so I am writing a code in another PHP file where I can get All values for this input . How to do this?

```
printf('<input type="text" name="%s" value="%s" /><br/>', $fieldName,$fieldValue );
```

i tried this which is not working

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $value = $_POST[$fieldName]; 
print_r ($value); }
```

and I want to get all the value of all inputs as this input is generated in a for loop and its in thousands.I hope you can get my question now

this post value is not getting any value when i submit form

Comment: It's so vague! Please describe what the variables are, and what do you want them to be.

Comment: You''ll likely need to create an array to store each and every fieldName as theyre output, so you can then iterate back over that to retrieve them, but your question is quite vague so Im not really sure what you want.  Also what is $index? and where are you declaring it?

Comment: @Rozeena Check my answer. You will get all the posted inputs in `$all_values` as key-value pairs. No for loop required.

Comment: @Ulver I tried yours also Notice: Undefined variable: fieldName in C:\xampp\htdocs\ Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: I took those variables names are from your example in the question. I assumed you were setting those variables value from some large array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply write

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
exit();
```

and you will get array which will help you.

Comment: Thank you for help . And what if there are more than one $_POST like if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        
      $name = $_POST[$fieldName];
      $value = $_POST[$fieldValue]; }

Comment: $_POST will display all the possible POSTED values . The out put array will display you everything .  'field_name'=> 'value'

Answer (score 2):

This is the code that you can use:

```
foreach ($value as $key => $value1) {
//$value1 has the value of your each input type array, you can use that value in this loop in the way you wish to.
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: $value = $_POST[$fieldName];  this is not getting the value of input field

Comment: i assumed `$fieldName` as the name of input type array in your form, this means that your name attribute is not correct in the form, please check the `printf()` function then. It should be of format: `name=yourname[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try using an array input field:

```
printf('<input type="text" name="name[%s]" value="%s" /><br/>', $fieldName,$fieldValue );
```

Then get the all posted inputs for "name" as:

```
$all_values = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : Array();
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: fieldName in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\

Comment: This is not a complete code of course. I was showing that you could use array input field based on the code in your question.